# Keep cursor within the web page when tabbing, prevent it from going outside to browser address bar

Tags: jquery

After I tab to and subsequently, leave the last input textbox on my page, I wish to travel to the first textbox once again.

I **never want the cursor in any case to jump out of the web page, usually ending up in the Bowser ADDRESS BAR area**.

Anyone have tested and proven a reliable method

Thanks for any contribution ;-)

Robert

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnBlur event, and then set focus back to your text box.

See this question and answer: [How to re-focus to a text field when focus is lost on a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605974/how-to-re-focus-to-a-text-field-when-focus-is-lost-on-a-html-form)